# Hyperlinks missing in printed documents

Tags: pdf, pages, printing

I've noticed this on several occasions where I'll print a document (Pages file, RTF, PDF, etc) and any hyperlinks in the document don't appear on the printed page. Where the hyperlinked text appears on screen it turns blue with an underscore (as expected), but on the printed page a white gap is left where the text should be as if the font has been changed to white.

Is this a known issue? This bug has become apparent to me since upgrading to OS X 10.7. I recently updated to 10.7.2 in hope that it would be resolved in that release but it wasn't. The only way I can find around this is to remove the hyperlink from the text and re-print the document which isn't great when I want the hyperlinks to look like links to begin with.

Any ideas on how I can solve this problem and if there's a known fix? I've been unable to find anything on the Apple forums as of yet :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was driver related, so I'm answering my on question in case it helps others. I downloaded the latest version of the printer drivers from the manufacturer's website and I have not received the issue since.

Answer (score 1):

One potential cause of this problem is hardware-related.

If you have a color inkjet printer and the blue ink is empty, this could cause the problem you describe. If it happened that you ran out of blue ink at the same time you upgraded, it might appear to be linked to the OS upgrade, but in fact would not be.

Comment: Hello, I hadn't actually checked that until now but the ink levels are high and printing a test page shows blue ink isn't low.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by reinstalling the printer drivers. Not entirely sure why it happened to begin with but it's resolved now.

Comment: Glad something worked for you!